# Java: HashSet what is the Compare concept?

Tags: java, set, language-concepts

Coming from a c++ world, I find reading of the HashSet documentation somewhat hard:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

In c++, you would have:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

which in turns points to:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare

Which makes it obvious the requirement for the type of element handled by a `std::set`. My question is: What are the requirements for the type (E) of elements maintained by a `Set` in Java ?

Here is a short example which I fail to understand:

```
import gdcm.Tag;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class TestTag
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
      Tag t1 = new Tag(0x8,0x8);
      Tag t2 = new Tag(0x8,0x8);
      if( t1 == t2 )
        throw new Exception("Instances are identical" );
      if( !t1.equals(t2) )
        throw new Exception("Instances are different" );
      if( t1.hashCode() != t2.hashCode() )
        throw new Exception("hashCodes are different" );
      Set<Tag> s = new HashSet<Tag>();
      s.add(t1);
      s.add(t2);
      if( s.size() != 1 )
        throw new Exception("Invalid size: " + s.size() );
    }
}
```

The above simple code fails with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Invalid size: 2 at TestTag.main(TestTag.java:42)
```

From my reading of the documentation only the equals operator needs to be implemented for Set:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

What am I missing from the documentation ?

Comment: Every object has `hashCode` implemented, as the default impl is present in `Object`. Whether that can/should be optimized is another question.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of the Tag class?

Comment: @Eran the whole point of my question is to answer it without the actual Tag implementation (language concept tag).

Comment: @malat Your exception makes no sense. If `t1.equals(t2)` and `t1.hashCode() == t2.hashCode()`, `s.size()` should be 1, since `HashSet` would consider `t1` and `t2` to be identical. Perhaps the code that gave you the exception you mentioned is not the code you posted.

Comment: Only problem is, without the `Tag` implementation, you do not have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  For this reason, it could be argued that this question is off-topic, as I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: The C++ `set` *"contains a sorted set of unique objects of type Key. Sorting is done using the key comparison function **`Compare`**"*. The Java equivalent of that is [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) (not `HashSet`): *The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a **`Comparator`** provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.*

Comment: Is it transitive? ie. You've shown `t1.equals(t2)` but does `t2.equals(t1)`? If the `hashCode` is equal, and `.equals` returns true, that is all you need to know. The Set will only keep one element.

Comment: As mentioned by @Eran it's not possible to get the exception you claim you got with the code you posted. Unless you broke `equals` or `hashCode` on purpose Please post your actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried to reproduce your issue, and maybe you just didn't override equals and/or hashSet correctly.

Take a look at my incorrect implemenation of Tag:

```
public class Tag {

private int x, y;

public Tag(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public boolean equals(Tag tag) {
    if (x != tag.x) return false;
    return y == tag.y;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = x;
    result = 31 * result + y;
    return result;
}
}
```

Looks quite ok doesn't it? But the problem is, I actually do not override the correct equals method, I overloaded it with my own implementation.

To work correctly, equals has to look like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Tag tag = (Tag) o;

    if (x != tag.x) return false;
    return y == tag.y;
}
```

Comment: Nice way to break it. I just used a boolean that returns true first time and then false.

Comment: Indeed I used the wrong signature for `equals` function, kindda hard to track in my case since I used swig to generate the java code.

Comment: As a general tip when programming in Java: Always use the @Override annotation. This also helps if you sometime in the future change the signature of a super class and then suddenly the subclasses behave strange.

Comment: As said above the java code was generated by an engine: swig. But I'll keep this trick burried in mind now :)

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing from the documentation ?

You are looking at the wrong part of the documentation.

The C++ [`set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is an *"sorted set of unique objects"*, and are *"usually implemented as red-black trees."*

In Java, [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is a more abstract concept (it's an interface, not a class) with multiple implementations, most notably the [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) and the [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) *(ignoring concurrent implementations)*.

As you can probably guess from the name alone, the Java `TreeSet` is the equivalent of the C++ `set`.

As for requirements, `HashSet` uses the [`hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) and [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) methods. They are defined on the `Object` class, and needs to be overridden on classes that needs to be in a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) or as keys in a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

For [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and keys of [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), you have two options: Provide a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) when creating the `TreeSet` (similar to C++), or have the objects implement the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

Comment: Thanks for actually reading my question carefully, indeed now I see the correct signature for `equals()` method.

Comment: I now understand that in Java `Set<Tag>` is in fact `Set<Object>` which may be obvious to all java devs (which explains the downvote), but that is counterintuitive to most c++ programmer.

Comment: @malat The downvote (at least mine) is because you didn't post the relevant code which would've made answering you simple. "Set<Tag> is in fact Set<Object>" that's far from being correct, java generics are much more complicated then that and they are very different then c++ templates.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this was simply a combination of bad luck and misunderstanding of HashSet requirement. Thanks to @christophe for help, I realized the issue when I tried adding in my swig generated Tag.java class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
}
```

I got the following error message:

```
gdcm/Tag.java:78: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
1 error
1 warning
```

Which meant my error was simply:

- I had the wrong signature in the first place: `boolean equals(Object o)` != `boolean equals(Tag t)`

The hint was simply to use the `@Override` keyword.

---

For those asking for the upstream code, the Java code is generated by swig. The original c++ code is here:

- https://github.com/malaterre/GDCM/blob/master/Source/DataStructureAndEncodingDefinition/gdcmTag.h